Como actualizar la tabla de adminlt jeroennoten con ajax para no recargar la pagina al insertar un nuevo registro con el framework laravel
Esto es el index de mi controller. $heads contiene los titulos de mi tabla, $positions obtiene los registros de la tabla y uso foreach para darle el formato a $config para que sin usar un foreach en blade se carguen los registros en la tabla. No se como combinar ambas herramientas nunca use ajax pero vi varios tutoriales pero ninguno usa la tabla de adminlt solo usan datatable.
   public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $heads=['ID','NOMBRE','FECHA CREACION','ULTIMA ACTUALIZACION','ESTADO','ACCIONES'];
        $positions=Position::where('active_position',1)->get();
        foreach($positions as $position){
            $config['data'][]=[$position->id,
            $position->name_position,
            $position->created_at,
            $position->updated_at,
            $position->active_position,
            
            '<td>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default text-teal mx-1 shadow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalShowPosition{{$row->id}}" title="Details">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-eye"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default text-primary mx-1 shadow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditPosition{{$row->id}}" title="Edit">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-pen"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default text-danger mx-1 shadow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDeletePosition{{$row->id}}" title="Delete">
                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-trash"></i>
                </button>
            </td>'

        ];
        }
        
        return view('positions.index',compact('heads'),compact('config'));
        

    }

Este es el codigo de mi vista
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Cargos')

@section('content_header')
    <h1><strong>Cargos</strong></h1><br>
    
    @include('positions.create')
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCreatePosition">Agregar</button>
@stop
@section('content')

@if ($errors->any())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <x-adminlte-alert theme="danger" icon="fa fa-times" title="ERROR" dismissable>
            {{ $error}}
        </x-adminlte-alert>
    @endforeach  
@endif

<x-adminlte-datatable id="table5" :heads="$heads" theme="light" :config="$config" striped hoverable with-buttons>
</x-adminlte-datatable >
@stop


Hola. Si observas aquí: foreach($positions as $position){, has declarado que cada item de $positions se llamará $position, pero luego, al crear los td, usas $row para referirte a esos items. Entonces, para que sea más simple, declara el bucle así: foreach($positions as $row){ o si prefieres, cambia los $row por $position.

Pero más allá de eso quiero actualizar con ajax la tabla y eso es lo que no sé cómo hacer ese código row era para lo modales para update y delete eso no tiene tanta importancia
